# Symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Find $\sigma$ in $S_5$ that fulfills:
$$\sigma(12)(34)=\sigma^{-1}(13)(45)$$
Can anyone help with that? i've tried to multiply by $\sigma^{-1}$ from the right side but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere

Comment: Try multiplying by $\sigma$ on the left and $(12)(34)$ on the right.

Comment: why does a $5$ appear there?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Heh, good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $\sigma^2=(13)(45)(12)(34)=(12354)$
Clearly $\sigma$ must be a $5$-cycle also, so we get $\sigma=\sigma^6=(12354)^3=(15243)$